# Can I traverse symlinked directories in Ruby with a "**" glob?

Tags: ruby, symlink

In Ruby, `Dir.glob("**/*.rb")` (for instance) doesn't traverse symlinked directories.  Is it possible to get the `**` to traverse symlinks?

I'm using two gems which find files this way, but I need them to see files within a symlinked directory.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Jonathan's clever and cunning approach is great, capable of slashing through hordes of symlinks with but a mere flick of a few asterisks, muahaha. However, it has the unfortunate side-effect of not returning immediate-child matches.  An improved version might be:

```
Dir.glob("**{,/*/**}/*.rb")
```

Which will (in my tests) do both follow one symlink and return immediate children.

Comment: Definitely works as it's referenced in the source code a popular open source project `parralel_spec` https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/blob/f680c77335dafe579022da7e76b4a168d92c8bf0/lib/parallel_tests/test/runner.rb#L221-L223

Answer (score 12):

Normally not with recursive search due to the risk of infinite loops.

But, [this discussion may help](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-talk-google/browse_thread/thread/e319f62f55cdea31?pli=1):

> `Dir.glob("**/*/**/b")` will follow a symlink up to once.