# Difference between pattern syntax in RSpec::Core::RakeTask and Pathname/Dir.glob

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, glob, rake-task

1. If I do a `.glob('**/spec')` then the recursive part guarantees that a directory named `spec` in the current directory will be captured. If I do a `task.pattern = '**/spec/**/*_spec.rb'` with `RSpec::Core::RakeTask` then tests inside spec in the current directory are not executed. They will be if the pattern is `spec/**/*_spec.rb`. What is the difference with patterns in `RSpec::Core::RakeTask` and `.glob` and why?
2. According to the documentation the default pattern for RSpec is `**/*_spec.rb`. Why is this different than the default `spec/**{,/*/**}/*_spec.rb` for `RSpec::Core::RakeTask` (specifically `**` versus `**{,/*/**}`; I assume this is related to the first question)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How glob patterns are used in `RSpec::Core::RakeTask`**

`RSpec::Core::RakeTask` just runs the `rspec` executable. Setting a task's pattern just passes the pattern with the `--pattern` flag.

RSpec first constructs a list of paths in which to look for specs. If no files or directories are given on the command line, a single default path is used, 'spec'. RSpec looks for the pattern in each path. [If the pattern begins with the path, RSpec just globs the pattern. If the pattern doesn't begin with the path, RSpec prepends the path to the pattern.](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L1789) So:

- The pattern `**/spec/**/*_spec.rb` begins with a wildcard, so RSpec prepends the path, and `spec/**/spec/**/*_spec.rb` doesn't match anything.
- The pattern `spec/**/*_spec.rb` begins with the path, so RSpec just uses it and it works.

The pattern `**/*_spec.rb` would also work; RSpec would prepend `spec/`.

**`RSpec::Core::RakeTask`'s default pattern**

[This part of the pattern `**{,/*/**}` allows it to follow symlinks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357754/can-i-traverse-symlinked-directories-in-ruby-with-a-glob) I don't know why `RSpec::Core::RakeTask` follows symlinks by default and command-line `rspec` doesn't.

I believe the the rake task's default pattern only works because RSpec recognizes that it begins with the path and doesn't prepend the path. I think if it were `**{,/*/**}/*_spec.rb` it would be clearer and would work in more situations.